# jQuery select x div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide() the 2nd and 3rd div with class second inside div.first

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="another"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>  // Hide this
    <div class="second"></div> // Hide this
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="another"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="second"></div> // Hide this
    <div class="second"></div> // Hide this
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

How can I select that every 2nd and 3rd div inside first class
with jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nth-child` for that

```
$('.second:nth-child(3), .second:nth-child(4)', '.first').hide();
```

```js
$('.second:nth-child(3), .second:nth-child(4)', '.first').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
    <div class="another">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="second">3</div>  <!-- Hide this -->
    <div class="second">4</div>  <!-- Hide this -->
    <div class="second">5</div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="another">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="second">3</div>  <!-- Hide this -->
    <div class="second">4</div>  <!-- Hide this -->
    <div class="second">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.each()` , `.slice()`

```js
$(".first").each(function() { $(".second", this).slice(1,3).hide() })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="first">
    <div class="another"></div>
    <div class="second">first</div>
    <div class="second">second</div>  // Hide this
    <div class="second">third</div> // Hide this
    <div class="second">fourth</div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="another"></div>
    <div class="second">first</div>
    <div class="second">second</div>  // Hide this
    <div class="second">third</div> // Hide this
    <div class="second">fourth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors.

```
$('.second:gt(0):lt(2)', '.first').hide();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/skk3qf2y/)